# "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set" while servlet deploying

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm triyng to deploy a spring-mvc webapp WAR-package on tomcat. Deploy proccess fails with following error: 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set'

I guess something wrong with my configuration :(

- Tomcat version: 8.5.46
- Spring, spring-mvc version: 5.1.9.RELEASE
- Example configuration code from spring.io: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-servlet

My webapp initializer:

```java
package com.jbtits.spring.mvc.webac;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.register(AppConfig.class);
        applicationContext.refresh();

        DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet(applicationContext);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = servletContext.addServlet("webac", servlet);
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registration.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

My webapp configuration:

```java
package com.jbtits.spring.mvc.webac;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc 
@ComponentScan("com.jbtits.spring.mvc.webac")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
}
```

Thats it, only two beans.

Tomcat failure output:

> 02-Oct-2019 18:02:52.971 WARNING [http-nio-8081-exec-84] org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set

Comment: Don't extend `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`, either implement `WebMvcConfigurere` or if on older version extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`.

Comment: Instead of WebApplicationInitializer, try extending 
AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer and override "getServletMappings", "getRootConfigClasses" and "getServletConfigClasses".

Comment: Same behaviour, cause ```org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextAwareProcessor``` can't set ```ServletContext``` (it's not existing at this time moment). This ```PostProcessor``` uses in both vaiarts

Comment: Too hard, isn't?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution: no need to call `applicationContext.refresh();` in the `org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer#onStartup`, cause it will be automaticaly called in the method `org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet#configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext` while servlet loading in the servlet container.

But I use example from spring.io docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-servlet . Why they use it that way?
[proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLXV9.png)